# Add product with Attributes size and color to cart using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need help in Reactjs app 'Add to cart'. I am using redux and to add products to cart with quantity and everything going right until tried to add specific attributes such as size or color and I don't know how to handle this can anyone explain me the logic to do it?